# how to securely open a document such that user is not able to copy the file

Tags: security, encryption

I am working on a project on which I need to send pdf/xls/doc files(using sd-card) to one mobile device 'A' in encrypted form along with the key to decrypt the files (Initially I am sending key, but user can also get that key if he knows where I would be storing the key, I have to think about this other way round).

To open a file, I will first decrypt and it will be loaded into RAM. So, basically there is a copy of file present.

I wanted to know if there is any way in which decryption and opening of file can be done in a secure way such that the mobile device 'A' user is not able to copy the decrypted file and send it over to another device.

Is there a way such that, only the page that is visible to the user is decrypted and as soon as he/she scrolls down/up, accordingly the page gets decrypted and view-able to user?

Comment: Does the solution need to prevent `A` user from pointing a photographic device at the screen and taking a picture? Because if so, you might spot that there are some issues with trying to achieve it. And if not, what sorts of copying are you actually trying to prevent?

Comment: Taking a picture is not the case that I need to take care of.

Comment: It is just that user should not be able to copy the content of the file into some other file. and send it to some other device.

Answer (score 0):

In the broadest sense, it's not possible. An important note: If you're sending an encrypted file along with the decryption key, you are NOT sending an encrypted document. It's analogous to giving your house key to someone, then claiming that your home is secure because the door is locked.

If you write your own code to render documents you can decrypt a page at a time and re-encrypt that page when it's not being viewed, all in RAM. It depends on the document format though, some formats may require you decrypt other parts in order to display a certain page. Alternatively you could just decrypt it in RAM and display it from there.

It doesn't matter though, because you'll encounter a plethora of problems.

- Swapfiles. Parts of you decrypted documents are going to end up in swap, you have very little control over this outside of manufacturing your own device and/or firmware.
- A user can take a screenshot or copy/paste page-by-page.
- They can modify your application to either decrypt and dump the entire document, never re-encrypt pages, and so on.
- They can use the key to decrypt the document on their own. If you're using a known algorithm, there are hundreds of libraries they can choose from.
- They can just manually type the text into another document.

Probably more issues too. Encryption done properly will stop a 3rd party from learning the contents of the documents, it doesn't stop the intended recipient from reading it. You need a trustworthy recipient and a strong policy. In addition, mobile devices are inherently bad for storing sensitive data since you carry them everywhere and probably use them for other purposes too. They're also easy to lose/have stolen.